# to keep the order of FLEX Datagrid columns as its dataprovider?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

The flex DataGrid colums are arranged alphabetically by default. I need  to order the DataGrid colums as per the order in its dataProvider. The dataprovider is the result of the HTTPService . And the number of columns is not known to us . The number of columns depends on the HTTPService result.

Any help is appriciated.

Thank you.

Comment: normally they appear in same order as in dataprovider plz check or provide some code snippet

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply.

I got the solution to my problem.
I got the column order while retrieving data and created columns in the same order in my datagrid before populating the datagrid. After all columns with the required column order were added to the datagrid, dataprovider provided data to the datagrid.

cheers!